# Retrofit is not working in android

Tags: android, retrofit

Hi I am a beginner in android.

In my app, I am using Retrofit for integrating web services, but I am getting a 404 error from the server!

My code is below, please help me.

### MainActivity:-

```
  String url = "MY URL";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //making object of RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();
        //Creating Rest Services
        RestInterface restInterface = adapter.create(RestInterface.class);

        restInterface.getWheatherReport(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Model> models, Response response) {
                System.out.println("Response is====>" + response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                System.out.println("failure is====>" + error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

### Model:-

```
private int paymenttypeid;
    private String cardType;

    public int getPaymenttypeid() {
        return paymenttypeid;
    }

    public void setPaymenttypeid(int paymenttypeid) {
        this.paymenttypeid = paymenttypeid;
    }

    public String getCardType() {
        return cardType;
    }

    public void setCardType(String cardType) {
        this.cardType = cardType;
    }
```

### RestInterface:-

```
 @GET("/weather?q=London,uk")
    void getWheatherReport(Callback<List<Model>> cb);
```

### Server response:-

```
[
  {
    "paymenttypeid": 1,
    "cardType": "Master Card"
  },
  {
    "paymenttypeid": 2,
    "cardType": "VISA"
  }
]
```

Comment: Error 404 means that your url is most likely wrong... what makes sense because your endpoint is: "URL"

Comment: define your String url = "URL";

Comment: no my url is correct

Comment: Could you Please check  URL with postman and get request . Checked it first whether it is working or not.

Comment: @Krish you should setLogLevel to LogLevel.FULL so you would see exactly which URL your retrofit is calling, it might be encoding the commas & therefore calling a wrong URL

Comment: failure is====>retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found

Comment: when i use volley getting response why not for Retrofit ?

Comment: please ensure first that this url api (GET OR POST) is working on some restclient or postman. if it is working fine there, then only this question will be valid

Comment: yes it's working fine in postman

Answer (score 0):

Change the String url = "URL" to something like: "http://www.yourapi.com/something" and you will be fine

Comment: you mean this? 

@GET("/weather?q=London,uk") 
    void getWheatherReport(Callback<List<Model>> cb);

Comment: No no in my code i given my server link instead of  String url = "URL"

Comment: in URL place i placed my ur but no result coming 404

Comment: i am not understanding why it is coming

Comment: Ok. Try to put this link in your browser, with the getWheatherReport path, in your browser. What do you get?

Comment: in my browser getting response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129034/discussion-between-leandro-borges-ferreira-and-krish).